# The picture can't display in the google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

python, pyecharts, google colab
It seems get the picture, but why can's see anything
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLOmf.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyecharts.globals import CurrentConfig, NotebookType  
CurrentConfig.NOTEBOOK_TYPE = NotebookType.JUPYTER_LAB
from pyecharts.charts import Bar
from pyecharts import options as opts

# V1 版本开始支持链式调用
bar = (
    Bar()
    .add_xaxis(["衬衫", "毛衣", "领带", "裤子", "风衣", "高跟鞋", "袜子"])
    .add_yaxis("商家A", [114, 55, 27, 101, 125, 27, 105])
    .add_yaxis("商家B", [57, 134, 137, 129, 145, 60, 49])
    .set_global_opts(title_opts=opts.TitleOpts(title="某商场销售情况"))
)
bar.render()

# 不习惯链式调用的开发者依旧可以单独调用方法
bar = Bar()
bar.add_xaxis(["衬衫", "毛衣", "领带", "裤子", "风衣", "高跟鞋", "袜子"])
bar.add_yaxis("商家A", [114, 55, 27, 101, 125, 27, 105])
bar.add_yaxis("商家B", [57, 134, 137, 129, 145, 60, 49])
bar.set_global_opts(title_opts=opts.TitleOpts(title="某商场销售情况"))
# bar.load_javascript() 
# bar.render()
bar.render_notebook()
```

Comment: I have replicated the example shown in https://towardsdatascience.com/make-the-cutest-chart-in-python-visualize-your-data-with-hand-drawn-charts-f21157f76b4b and I have the same problem. Nothing shows when I run the chart.render_notebook(). Any suggestions? Thanks!